# Handling REST Client Status Code in Ballerina

Tags: ballerina

I am invoking a REST service and if the status code is 404 I need to return (). Or else I need to convert it into a record type. This is the approach I followed. But in this approach, I had to invoke the REST endpoint twice. Is there a way this code can be optimised?

```
    http:Response response = check gitHubApiClient->/repos/[owner]/[repoName]/contents/[expression];
    if response.statusCode === http:STATUS_NOT_FOUND {
        log:printError(string `File not found in the repository ${repoName}`);
        return ();
    }
    types:RepositoryContent repoContent = check gitHubApiClient->/repos/[owner]/[repoName]/contents/[expression];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `getJsonPayload()` to retrieve the payload from the initial response and then use `fromJsonWithType()` or `cloneWithType()` methods to convert the JSON payload to your user defined type.

```
return (check response.getJsonPayload()).cloneWithType(types:RepositoryContent);
```

You can refer below documentation to get a better idea,

[1](https://central.ballerina.io/ballerina/http/latest#Response-getJsonPayload) [getJsonPayload](https://central.ballerina.io/ballerina/http/latest#Response-getJsonPayload)

[2](https://ballerina.io/learn/by-example/convert-from-json-to-user-defined-type/) [convert from JSON to user-defined type](https://ballerina.io/learn/by-example/convert-from-json-to-user-defined-type/)